# org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query

Tags: java, xpath, jsoup, xsoup

i'm using Xsoup.

this is the code:

```
private void updateSeed(Document document) {
 mappingParser
        .setSeed(Xsoup.compile("//div[@class='pgCell'][last()]/a/@href")
        .evaluate(document).get());
}
```

when i execute the previous function i'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'div[@class='pgCell'][last()]': unexpected token at 'last()'
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.byFunction(XPathParser.java:225)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.consumePredicates(XPathParser.java:202)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.findElements(XPathParser.java:138)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:51)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:375)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.combinator(XPathParser.java:85)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:49)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:375)
    at us.codecraft.xsoup.Xsoup.compile(Xsoup.java:27)
    at com.qannoufit.test.CrawlerController.updateSeed(CrawlerController.java:102)
    at com.qannoufit.test.CrawlerController.populateShouldParse(CrawlerController.java:91)
    at com.qannoufit.test.CrawlerController.startCrawling(CrawlerController.java:60)
    at com.qannoufit.test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: Seems that you just can't use `last()` as it isn't listed in supported xpath syntax by xsoup according to [xsoup GitHub Readme](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CSS selector instead. The initial xPath query could be translated like below:

```
div.pgCell:last-of-type > a
```

Once you have the anchor, gets its href.

```
private void updateSeed(Document document) {
  Element anchor = document.select("div.pgCell:last-of-type > a").first();
  if (anchor==null) {
     // Anchor not found, handle error here...
  }

  mappingParser.setSeed(anchor.absUrl("href"));
}
```